# How can I activate SELinux on Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS

Tags: ubuntu, selinux

I'm trying to enable SELinux on my Ubuntu 20 VPS. I've installed the necessary utilities based on [this article](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-disable-enable-selinux-on-ubuntu-20-04-focal-fossa-linux), and when I run `sudo selinunx-activate`, it says it's activated, but if I run `sestatus`, it says it's disabled. I tried rebooting, but it still says it's disabled afterward.

```
~$ sudo selinux-activate
Activating SE Linux
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub.d/init-select.cfg'
Generating grub configuration file ...
Warning: Setting GRUB_TIMEOUT to a non-zero value when GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT is set is no longer supported.
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-61-generic
done
SE Linux is activated.  You may need to reboot now.
~$ sestatus
SELinux status:                 disabled
```

How do I activate SELinux?

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming questions. You might try asking on [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/), [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/), or [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/) instead.

Answer (score 0):

Edit `/etc/selinux/config` to include `SELINUX=permissive` and reboot. This mode logs warnings but doesn't enforce them so you can work out any bugs in the policy. When you're ready to test, use `setenforce 1` to temporarily put SELinux into enforcing mode until changed back with `setenforce 0` or a reboot. When you're ready to have the system go directly into enforcing mode at boot, change the config file line above to `SELINUX=enforcing` and reboot.